# Quicken File transfer Mac to Mac

Tags: mac

What is the easiest and safest way to transfer all Quicken files from one Mac to another Mac that already has Quicken on it? Firewire and target disk work?

Comment: What's "Quicken"? OS X software?

Comment: @Juri: Quicken is accounting software made by Intuit.

Comment: @Chealion: Wha is Intuit? :P

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: The company who caused my Twitter feed to be filled with "I'm deleting my account from mint.com"? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of file you could even email it to yourself or take it on a USB key if that's a necessary option - but across the network will suffice and is usually the quickest and easiest option unless the file is extremely large (>2GB or so - whenever sneaker net can be faster)

Big warning however:

Quicken Data files **use** their Resource Fork to store information. If you use a tool to move the file that does not support resource forks or copy the file to a place that does not keep resource forks around(1). The Finder, and your standard `cp`, `mv`, `rsync` on Mac OS X 10.4 and higher *do* support resource forks thankfully.

1 - Mac OS X attempts to keep resource forks around by making a separate file with a `._` in front of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of another way that would be faster. Of course you need to be sure to check the Read/Write attributes of the file after the xfer. And I would run a Permissions repair after the xfer to make sure those are correct.

Comment: What permissions repair? If you mean the one from disk utility that will not look at data files - just files that have receipts from the installer.

Answer (score 0):

A single network cable should work.  You should get gigabit ethernet (1000kb/s).  Also, I don't believe that you need a crossover cable with gigabit.